# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SQL": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SQL * FROM Employers WHERE id =?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, sql-select

Estou tentando fazer o `SELECT` abaixo passando um valor como parâmetro na pesquisa, Só que continua dando o mesmo erro.

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SQL": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SQL * FROM Employers WHERE id = ?

Qual é o problema do meu `SELECT`?

```
public Employer getEmployerProfile(String parameter) {
     String sql = "SQL * FROM Employers WHERE id = ?";

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{parameter});

    c.moveToFirst();

    Employer employerProfile = new Employer();
    employerProfile.setName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
    employerProfile.setAddress(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")));


    return employerProfile;
}
```

Formato dos campos na tabela:

```
private String createTableEmployers() {
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE Employers (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL, email TEXT NOT NULL, address TEXT, status TEXT, confirmationStatus TEXT)";
    return sql;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linguagem SQL não possui um comando chamado SQL, existe um `SELECT` então provavelmente o que queria usar era:

```
SELECT * FROM Employers WHERE id = ?
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Query.sql).

Normalmente a mensagem de erro é bem informativa quanto ao erro. Sempre que lê-la com atenção já acha o erro sem maiores problemas. Só nesta página o erro aparece 5 vezes. Programar é atenção aos detalhes, não é só copiar e colar sem prestar atenção ao que está aparecendo.

Este código pode ser simplificado, mas isto é outro assunto.

Comment: Obrigado, foi falta de atencao mesmo. Acho que ja estava viciado no erro. Como posso simplificar o código?